# Unexpected identifier when concatenate string from codebehind on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is a very small bug that I have been trying figure out for couple hours.

Considering this code behind

```
using System;

public partial class Controls_DashboardGraph : InboundOutboundControl
{
    public string GraphTitle
    {
        get
        {
            if (2>1) //To simply the logic, it will always meets this condition
            {
                return "The World";
            }
            else
            {
                return "All Cocoms";
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Somelogic here
    }
}
```

It has a **GraphTitle** variable in it.

And I am trying to use the value the front page to perform an online string concatenation

```
<%@ control language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" codefile="DashboardGraph.ascx.cs" inherits="Controls_DashboardGraph" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var title = <%= this.GraphTitle%>;
    var isInBound = "true";
    <%
    if (3>2) //To minimize the code, simply the logic here
    {
    %>
        path = `Services/ChartData.asmx/RetrieveChart?title=${title}&inbound=${isInBound}`;
    <%
    }
    else
    {
    %>
        isInBound = "false";
        path = `Services/ChartData.asmx/RetrieveChart?title=${title}&inbound=${isInBound}`;
    <%
    }
    %>
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: path,
        success: function (data) {
             //DoSomething
        }
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to concatenate the string to get a path so I can use in ajax. However, when I do this, I got

> **'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'World'**

on line `var title = <%= this.GraphTitle%>;`;

**What I have tried:**

1: I thought it is because of the space in the string. However, when I changed the return value to "TheWorld", I got

> Uncaught ReferenceError: TheWorld is not defined

2: Different bee-stings
I have tried:<%# %>, didn't work either.

**What I need help with:**
I know this is a very trivial bug, but I have been bugged by it for a while. What is wrong here? why does this simply string concatenation throwing erros?

Comment: @mason Thank you. My brain got mixed up the syntax of C# and JS. Adding double quote solves it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
var title = <%= this.GraphTitle%>;
```

to this:

```
var title = "<%= Regex.Escape( this.GraphTitle ) %>";
```

- Note two things:

  1. The outer double-quotes `"`.
  2. The use of `Regex.Escape` as a poor-man's substitute to convert in-memory .NET `String` chars to an escaped JavaScript string, as JavaScript and .NET regex share many escape-sequences (though this approach isn't perfect, it works in a pinch).

     - So if `GraphTitle` contains a double-quote char then it will be rendered as a JS escaped quote, thus your JS `<script>` element won't  get garbled.